# The graph of algebraic theories

Tags: universal-algebra, ct.category-theory, algebraic-theory

Fix a logic $L$ and consider the category $\mathbf{AlgTh}_L$ with theories of $L$ as objects and theory interpretations as morphisms.  For nice enough logics, this category has pushouts (which we will assume is the case).

Question: how large a 'graph' has been actually built using this (old) idea?  There are plenty of flat lists of objects of such a category, for example Wikipedia has two: [algebraic structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_structure) and [list of algebraic structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_algebraic_structures) (with lots of overlap as well as being non-trivially different), Jipsen has a [list](http://math.chapman.edu/cgi-bin/structures/) (not all of which are properly defined) and a [graph](http://www1.chapman.edu/~jipsen/PCP/theoriesPO1.html) with 48 entries.  One can find other partial graphs too: page 136-141 of the [CASL reference manual](http://www.informatik.uni-bremen.de/~lschrode/papers/lib.pdf) or the specialized-for-groups graph of [Coq Theories](http://coqfinitgroup.gforge.inria.fr/) required to prove the Feit-Thompson theorem.  There are even [similar lists](http://www.cc.utah.edu/~nahaj/logic/structures/systems/index.html) for (modal) logics.  But I have yet to find a decent (categorical) graphs.  Has it not been done?

[I am interested in this because I am building such a graph, and I don't want to waste my time inventing things that have already been done.  Also, I want to be as complete as I can.]

Comment: I note that I think 3 of the links are broken at this point.